# If $f'(x)$ tends to $\infty$ then $f(x)$ does the same

Tags: analysis

I noticed that when $f'(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, then $f(x)$ must tend to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ as well. I'm stuck at the proof though.

If you implement the mean value theorem for $f(x)$ in $(x,x+1)$ you'll get:

$f(x+1) - f(x)= f'(b)$ where $b>x$

now if u take limits for $x\rightarrow+\infty$, b must tend to $+\infty$ as well.
So, $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ $f(x+1) - f(x)$ = $+\infty$, as $x$ tends to $+\infty$

Also, $f(x)$ must be increasing as $x$ tends to $+\infty$. Can somebody continue this or show me another way of proving this?

Answer (score 12):

Since $f'(x)\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$, there exists $x_0$ such that $f'(x)\geqslant1$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$. Thus, $f(x)\geqslant x-x_0+f(x_0)$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$. Since $x-x_0+f(x_0)\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$, this implies that $f(x)\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: did u just think of that? ._.

Comment: @Plom This comes from the interpretation of $f'$ as the "gradient" of the graph: The graph gets steeper, so clearly it lies above a line with gradient 1 when $x$ is large enough.

Comment: Plom: Are you able to expand on the "Thus" step?

Comment: @Did What justifies the inequality following the word "Thus,"?

Comment: @JackM Surely you can answer to *that*... :-)

Comment: (This is odd, I am nearly certain this answer was accepted at a time--but no more.)

Comment: do u mean the mean value theorem part? or the f'(x)>=1 ? the latter sounds legit :/

Comment: "Sounds legit" $\ne$ "is a full proof".

Comment: i cant prove it from looking at it right now, but i have a hunch it  can be proved with the definition of limits ._. ...just a hunch tho